# C# ObservableCollection Add error

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a custom control:

```
public class Detail
{
    public string Text {get; set;}
}

public class Header : Detail
{
    public int Size {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Detail> Details;
}

public class MyControl : Control
{
    public ObservableCollection<Header> Headers;
}
```

I add the control to a form, add a few Header objects, with each having a few Detail objects added to them. So far everything works fine.

However when I close the form and open it again, I'm getting the error:

Message 1   Method 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[Utils.Header, Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].Add' not found.

And the code in the formdesigner class is this:

```
Header header1 = new Utils.Header();

resources.ApplyResources(header1, "header1");
this.taskBar1.Headers.Add(header1);  //This line causes the error
```

What can the problem be?

Comment: Did you try to use xaml for achieving what you want?

Comment: *code in the formdesigner class* ouch, you do not edit `blablabla.Designer.cs` directly I hope?

Comment: @Tigran This is a WinForms project

Comment: @Sinatr No I just opened it to see the error line

Comment: Your code shows two ObservableCollections - `Details` and `Headers`, yet the error is on a member called `Groups`. Any chance you could include the relevant code?

Comment: @decPL My bad. That should be Headers.

Comment: You have two collection, both are different type.
You can assign Header object to Detail type collection but you can not in opposite direction assign Detail object to Header type collection.
They are covariant/contravariant issues, maybe here is the problem - you should bring some more code.

Comment: Why is the error 'Method Add not found'? The method is found when I use IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the ObservableCollection to BindingList and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on the classes and it looks like it's working fine.

Note: ObservableCollection is for WPF not WinForms!